# I can't place an order on IBapi through TWS

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws, ib-api

I am writing a service to work through the TWS API based on the Python language. Faced a problem when placing an order. these code are which I'm using, and always it says

> waiting for connection
> waiting for connection
> waiting for connection
> waiting for connection

I know that the problem is connecting API via orderId, but I don't know how to fix them.
Through the API settings, I checked everything that I need. Like Enabled activeX and socket client.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *

import threading
import time

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    
    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        self.nextorderId = orderId
        print('The next valid order id is: ', self.nextorderId)

    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFullPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print('orderStatus - orderid:', orderId, 'status:', status, 'filled', filled, 'remaining', remaining, 'lastFillPrice', lastFillPrice)
    
    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ':', order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId, execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)


def run_loop():
    app.run()

#Function to create FX Order contract
def FX_order(symbol):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = symbol[:3]
    contract.secType = 'CASH'
    contract.exchange = 'IDEALPRO'
    contract.currency = symbol[3:]
    return contract

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

app.nextorderId = None

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

#Check if the API is connected via orderid
while True:
    if isinstance(app.nextorderId, int):
        print('connected')
        print()
        break
    else:
        print('waiting for connection')
        time.sleep(1)

#Create order object
order = Order()
order.action = 'BUY'
order.totalQuantity = 1000
order.orderType = 'LMT'
order.lmtPrice = '1.10'

#Place order

# app.placeOrder(app.nextorderId, FX_order('EURUSD'), order)
#app.nextorderId += 1

time.sleep(3)

#Cancel order 
print('cancelling order')
app.cancelOrder(app.nextorderId)

time.sleep(3)
app.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add 127.0.0.1 to the Configuration -> API -> Settings -> Trusted API

Comment: Or, if your code IDE and TWS are in the same computer, you can just tick the `Allow connections from localhost only` in your TWS API setting and then you don't need to add the local default private IP Address into the Trusted IPs.